in gnucobol, sub programs of one parent can't invoke each other
I'm currently trying to achieve a pattern to write modest these days' programs in cobol.
By these days' programs I mean a source file with a few variables and procedures visible to each other.
The closest to my aim is a list of programs, each able to call each other, while the operating system is calling the first one.
To share the same variables, I had to mark them external. The drawback is, they are probably accessible in other sources eventually linked together.
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID. MAIN.
DATA DIVISION.
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
        01 MY-NAME PIC X(10) VALUE 'MAIN'.
        01 CALLS PIC 9(3) EXTERNAL.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    MOVE 0 TO CALLS.
    CALL 'CALL-SHOW' USING MY-NAME, 'CALL-SHOW'.
    CALL 'ROUTINE1' USING MY-NAME.
    CALL 'ROUTINE2' USING MY-NAME.
END PROGRAM MAIN.

IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID. CALL-SHOW.
DATA DIVISION.
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
        01 CALLS PIC 9(3) EXTERNAL.
    LINKAGE SECTION.
        01 CALLER PIC X(10).
        01 CALLED PIC X(10).
PROCEDURE DIVISION
    USING CALLER, CALLED.
    ADD 1 TO CALLS.
    DISPLAY CALLS ' CALLS' END-DISPLAY.
    DISPLAY CALLER ' CALLED ' CALLED END-DISPLAY.
    GOBACK.
END PROGRAM CALL-SHOW.

IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID. ROUTINE1.
DATA DIVISION.
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
        01 MY-NAME PIC X(10) VALUE 'ROUTINE1'.
        01 CALLS PIC 9(3) EXTERNAL.
    LINKAGE SECTION.
        01 CALLER PIC X(10).
PROCEDURE DIVISION USING CALLER.
    CALL 'CALL-SHOW' USING CALLER, MY-NAME.
    CALL 'CALL-SHOW' USING MY-NAME, 'CALL-SHOW'.
    CALL 'ROUTINE2' USING MY-NAME.
    GOBACK.
END PROGRAM ROUTINE1.

IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID. ROUTINE2.
DATA DIVISION.
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
        01 MY-NAME PIC X(10) VALUE 'ROUTINE2'.
        01 CALLS PIC 9(3) EXTERNAL.
    LINKAGE SECTION.
        01 CALLER PIC X(10).
PROCEDURE DIVISION USING CALLER.
    CALL 'CALL-SHOW' USING CALLER, MY-NAME.
    CALL 'CALL-SHOW' USING MY-NAME, 'CALL-SHOW'.
    GOBACK.
END PROGRAM ROUTINE2.


Another approach I tried is a program with global variables and a few other programs embedded within it's procedure division. Here the global variables are happily visible within that program, but the subprograms seem to be visible in the parent program only.
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. DemoGLOBAL.
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  Arg GLOBAL                     PIC X(10).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000-Main.
    MOVE ALL "X" TO Arg
    CALL "DemoSub" END-CALL
    DISPLAY "DemoGLOBAL: " Arg END-DISPLAY
    CALL "DemoSub2" END-CALL
    DISPLAY "DemoGLOBAL: " Arg END-DISPLAY
    CALL "DemoSub3" END-CALL
    GOBACK
    .
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. DemoSub.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000-Main.
    MOVE ALL "*" TO Arg.
    GOBACK
    .
END PROGRAM DemoSub.
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. DemoSub2.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000-Main.
    MOVE ALL "?" TO Arg.
    GOBACK
    .
END PROGRAM DemoSub2.
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. DemoSub3.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000-Main.
*>    CALL "DemoSub" END-CALL
    GOBACK
    .
END PROGRAM DemoSub3.
END PROGRAM DemoGLOBAL.

Is there a better approach have data and procedures source-wide?

your code does not have any external variables

sure @SimonSobisch, I'm editing the question right away.

ok, after further inquiring and even consulting gemini, i can fully adopt the following concept:

the main equivalent is a top level defined program.
any variable to be accessible to all code should be put in the main program data division and marked global.
additional full blown programs, from identification division. to end program. may be put in the procedure division of any of the said programs, and be considered nested subprograms.
nested subprograms are accessible from their parent program. to access a nested subprogram from it's siblings subprograms, it should be marked common as in the following example:

IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. DemoGLOBAL.
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  global-var GLOBAL                     PIC X(10).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000-Main.
    MOVE ALL "X" TO global-var
    CALL "DemoSub" END-CALL
    DISPLAY "DemoGLOBAL: " global-var END-DISPLAY
    CALL "DemoSub2" END-CALL
    DISPLAY "DemoGLOBAL: " global-var END-DISPLAY
    CALL "DemoSub3" END-CALL
    DISPLAY "DemoGLOBAL: " global-var END-DISPLAY
    GOBACK
    .
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. DemoSub common.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000-Main.
    MOVE ALL "*" TO global-var.
    GOBACK
    .
END PROGRAM DemoSub.
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. DemoSub2.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000-Main.
    MOVE ALL "?" TO global-var.
    GOBACK
    .
END PROGRAM DemoSub2.
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. DemoSub3.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000-Main.
    CALL "DemoSub" END-CALL
    GOBACK
    .
END PROGRAM DemoSub3.
END PROGRAM DemoGLOBAL.


of course, this was the way to bend experienced cobol to provide a modern style like 'module' with isolated functions / subprograms.
as my cobol exposure grows, i'd feel more confortable with performing sections and paragraphs, that could run in a module like my example, that has no parameters calling yet.
the subprograms are suitable to allow calling with parameters.

Your findings are right concerning the program-name scope (though I don't think it really matches the original question...) but the sample is bad because the COBOL point is that you use CALL USING`` and LINKAGEto pass the address of the shared data around - in this caseARG` should be passed that way, making it accessible to all subs "as expected" (no matter how it is "locally" named).
This will then also work with and without nested programs.

thank you @SimonSobisch for your comment. indeed the parameters should normally be as isolated as they need to be, and different for each call. in fact, the only meaningful use of arg here was the global scope. but my problem was i wanted a module like program, of which each sub program can call it's common siblings, not only main could call sub programs, and all subprograms may access global data. and now the solution is given.

ok, changed arg to global-var.

EXTERNAL variables are visible to the whole runtime unit (= the process / pid)  and can be accessed by any program. It is "stored" in the runtime and its size must be identical in all programs (otherwise the first with a different size will either abort or cannot be CALLed, depending on the implementation).
GLOBAL is nicely described by the standard - just the way you found it working:

A global name is available to every program contained within the program
that declares it.

It is not 100% clear what you want to achieve; but it seems you want a common data used in all programs. The standard option would be that the "main" program (started from the operating system) has the data (defined in a copybook) in its WORKING-STORAGE (providing definition and data) while the other programs have it in LINKAGE (providing definition only) and reference it in PROCEDURE DIVISION USING (using the data passed by the program on CALL ... USING).
If you ever need to share the data between independent processes, you'd have LINKAGE only and share the data via operating system (or COBOL implementation) specific functions (like shmget on posix environments), with the first program allocating the memory dynamically.

Thank you @SimonSobisch for treating the subject. I kind of feel better with the global approach myself, but in this case, the subprograms seem to fall short of finding each other. Tou may see my source examples.
